# PL/SQL not fetching any rows with null values

Tags: php, plsql

I'm working with a PL/SQL connection trying to fetch rows from a dummie database. However, it does not seem to select any rows that have null values. Testing the same SQL commands on a command line does work.

I created the following test table:

```
CREATE TABLE test
( 
  id number(4) primary key,
  test_field VARCHAR(255)
);
```

And inserted the following dummy data:

```
INSERT INTO test
(id, test_field) VALUES (1, 'test1');

INSERT INTO test
(id, test_field) VALUES (2, NULL);
```

When I execute the folllowing SQL command on command line
    SELECT * FROM test;

I receive 2 rows, with the data as I expect it to be (2nd row has no test_field value)

However, executing the same command trough

```
$conn = oci_connect(..., ..., ...);
if (!$conn) { // error handling }
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM test');
oci_execute($stid);
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))) { 
    var_dump($row);
}
```

it doesn't reach anything inside the while.

This is abstracted sql data, when I test it with a larger data file it seems to fetch any rows that do not have null columns (I can post the dataset if requested). also, something like "SELECT 1, null FROM dual" does return the null values.

I've been banging my head on this now for a few hours. I hope any of you might be able to give me some pointers to what is going wrong.

Thank in advance!

Comment: Do you have `error_reporting()` on? Are you sure that you are even reaching the while loop without error? [The docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php) say that PL/SQL statements _should_ end with a `;`

Answer (score 0):

What versions of php and oracle ar you using? I tried to reproduce your problem, but got a perfect response:

```
array(2) {
  ["ID"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["TEST_FIELD"]=>
  string(5) "test1"
}
array(2) {
  ["ID"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["TEST_FIELD"]=>
  NULL
}
```

You should indeed turn on error_reporting like Michael suggests if you don't get any output at all.

Don't add a semicolon, because that will actually give you errors since this is a SQL statement, not a PL/SQL statement.

This is what the PHP documentation sais about that:

> SQL statements should not end with a semi-colon (";"). PL/SQL
>   statements should end with a semi-colon (";").